# Use IoC with old web service project

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, asmx

I got an old (2008) three layered back office system:

- Web service layer; asmx type web services. Probably made from the "ASP.NET Web Service Application"- template
- Business layer; I don't want to touch this.
- Data layer; A mess. All sorts of data access.

My goal is to clean up this, write some unit tests etc.

For a start; Is it possible to add an IoC-container. Where should it initialized? The project is currently running on .NET Framework 3.5.

Ivar

Comment: If your goal is to clean this up. Take the time to look at some design patterns and set yourself a goal for the final design of the application (a goal you might never reach, but just 'approach'). For instance, take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95) that describes how to write highly maintainable web services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have found good article for you

http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/asp-net-web-services-dependency-injection-using-unity/

In short words:

1. Set up DI/IoC container in global.asax.cs and have their Container property to access your DI/IoC container
2. Resolve your dependencies or build container in constructor of your service, or create a base class as the example shows
3. Optionally when you need you can resolve your dependency from container a-la "Service locator"